# what is this file .fdr in the directory Firebird

Tags: firebird

what is this file .fdr in the directory Firebird . For me, it weighs 16 gb. Is this a transaction log ? Or how to reduce it ?

Comment: As far as I know that is not a standard extension in Firebird. Firebird doesn't have a transaction log, because it applies a careful write strategy to write changes to the database immediately.

Comment: It could also be your database. How do you connect to your database?